# How can i get the Local Storage data using "Execute Javascript" Keyword in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

How can i get the Local Storage data using "Execute Javascript" Keyword in Robot Framework ......

**I have tried:**

Execute Javascript     function    getLocalStorage()       {console.log(window.localStorage.getItem('kctoken))}; return getLocalStorage();

Answer (score 1):

```
   ${yourKey}=    Execute Javascript   return window["localStorage"].getItem("yourkey")
```

maybe..

Comment: `maybe` isn't much of an explanation how this should help.

Comment: @greybeard maybe as in "I dont write js so there might be syntax errors but thats how it is supposed to work"

Answer (score 0):

you can give try to this
${tokenval}=    Execute Javascript    return window.localStorage.getItem("key")